# Vim FZF: sort initial results on file date

Tags: vim, fzf

I have this vim mapping:

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader><space> :Files<CR>
```

Is it possible to change the sorting on the initial list?
It would be nice to see recently changed files first.
When I start searching, the normal sorting from fzf is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know no easy way, no.

But you could just write a function which gets you the file list sorted by date (Note this is all untested):

```
let l:filelist = split(system(find . -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' | 
                              \ sort -k 1 -n | sed 's/^[^ ]* //'), 'n')
```

There are some other commands, depending on your enviroment which can be used. But here the first problems arise. That command listes all your files in your directory. To respect your gitignore or whatever more work is needed.
Also this is a lot slower than fzf!

Once you have the list, you can just use fzf again:

```
call fzf#run({'source': l:filelist, 'sink': 'e', 'down': '40%'})
```

So i think this could maybe work fine for small projects, but if you have a bigger project it is way to slow, also if you use something like rails which rebuilds your assets quite often, you will have to filter the result.

---

Update:

As mentioned in the comment from r03, you can also edit the `FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND` variable, if you want to use this globaly. No need to passing it to vimscript then.

Comment: Maybe with a tool like ag or ripgrep? But with ag, I don't see an option to print the date.

Comment: maybe, as i said, there are a loot of tools, and just to be clear, you don't need to print the date, you just have to sort it by the date

Comment: @r03 thank you for that update. That's actually a pretty good way to edit the FZF behaviour. How is the speed of your script ?

Comment: It's very fast for a normal project, but not usable on my complete home folder :-) I need to improve this. Maybe add a limit on the number of files or something. If the limit is reached, then no sorting.

Comment: @ro3 fzf is also slow on my home (~300k files), so thats nothing new. But fzf is avaible and useable while loading.